# dimension of an ideal (definition)

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal. When we refer to the "dimension" of $I$, what exactly do we mean? Is it the Krull dimension of $A/I$? In particular, i am trying to understand the meaning of the "dim" function in Macaulay2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe $\operatorname{dim} I$ can mean either of two things: $\operatorname{dim} A/I$ or $\operatorname{dim} I=\operatorname{dim} I /\operatorname{ann}(I)$, where we view $I$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: Do you have an example where the dimension of $I$ means $\operatorname{dim} I /\operatorname{ann}(I)$? Actually I never seen this!